# javascript split('"').join('char(34)') not working for string comm"""ent

Tags: javascript

I have a string: `comm"""ent`.
I have to convert it to this:

```
value(concat("comm",char(34),char(34),char(34),"ent")).
```

I used `value(concat(' + str.split('"').join('\",char(34),\"') + "))`
But that returns:

```
value(concat("comm",char(34),"",char(34),"",char(34),"","ent"))
```

A result containing `""` is not accepted by the processor.
I also tried a for loop but couldn't get that to work. How can I do this?

Comment: i have used 
value(concat(str.split('"').filter(function (str) {
    return str !== '';
}).join('",char(34)"')

It is returning value(concat("comm",char(34),"ent"))

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var str = "comm\"\"\"ent";
var str1 = str.split('"');
str1[0] = str1[0] + '"';
str1[str1.length-1] = ',"' + str1[str1.length-1];
str1.join(',char(34)');
```

This way you get: 
`"comm",char(34),char(34),char(34),"ent"`

Answer (score 0):

Just filter out empty strings:

```
var string = 'comm"""ent';
return 'value(concat(' + string.split(/(")/g).filter(Boolean).map(function(x) {
    return x=='"' ? 'char(34)' : '"'+x+'"';
}).join(',') + '))';
```